# What model to fit pseudo-logarithmic trend?

Tags: dataset, regression

I am dealing with a scatterplot where I am trying to figure out the relationship between two variables, but I have so far failed to identify what the best fit could be. The presence of zero values prevents me from using exponential and power law regression lines.

Zero values are not shown as the Y axis starts from 1, but they are present. My bad.

This is the scatterplot. To me it looks like this is some sort of logarithmic trend but I am not sure about it.

**What model will best interpret this trend?**

[image]

Comment: Here are a couple of valuable resources I discovered in a previous post in reference to a question I had on tools and IDE for both Oracle packages and SQL Server stored procedures. http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models (overall a total resource)
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/ (a company with a great set of database tools) HTH ~

Comment: What do the variables represent?

Comment: If you're just interested in curve fitting $y=a(1-x)^b$ (with $x$ rescaled) works well, but if you want a statistically justifiable choice, it would help to know more about the data.

Comment: Do you have the option to share the numerical data?

Comment: I have the option to share the data, although we are talking about two data series of `1000` observations each. But it would made no sense to discuss the nature of these data, as an extensive explanation of how they are obtained should come in the first place.

Comment: That's part of the discussion. Feel free to edit your post to include details, and a link to data.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take a curve fitting approach. For example, [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def f(x, a, b, c):
    "Rough functional form of the data"
    return a + b * (1 - np.exp(-c/x))

solution = curve_fit(f, c, y, p0=(3_500, 3_500, 200))
```